# example marathon json deployment file when using glusterfs volume driver

Tags: docker, mesos, devops, marathon, glusterfs

Hi didn't really knew if my question was more for serverfault or here, I hope devops won't mind me posting here.

I am working on a stack with **mesos/marathon/docker/glusterfs**, I feel tired with the lake of documentation.

I am looking for a sample marthon deployement file for deploying using [glusterfs](https://github.com/calavera/docker-volume-glusterfs) driver.

The author says that we should create the volume before, but he doesn't say anything about mounting it.

```
"container": {
 "type": "DOCKER",
 "docker": {
   "image": "kylemanna/openvpn:latest",
   "parameters": [
     {
       "key": "volume-driver",
       "value": "glusterfs"
     },
     {
       "key": "cap-add",
       "value": "NET_ADMIN"
     }
   ],
   "network": "BRIDGE",
   "portMappings": [
     {
       "containerPort": 1194
     } 
   ]
 },
 "volumes": [
   {
     "containerPath": "/etc/openvpn",
     "hostPath": "openvpn-data",
     "mode": "RW"
   }
 ]
}
```

My container keep restarting in marathon and logs says that `/usr/local/bin/ovpn_run: line 16: /etc/openvpn/ovpn_env.sh: No such file or directory`

On my gluster fileserver, I have these file present in `/data/openvpn-data/ovpn_env.sh`

I don't see any mount point in `/mnt`, I guess marathon did the mount itself, but because the container keep restarting, I dont see it.

I did a `docker inspect` to check where was stored the filesystem and I found that it is stored in `/var/lib/docker-volumes/_glusterfs/openvpn-data`

So here are my questions :

- Is my marathon json file correct ?
- Will the container wait for all data to be downloaded and should I configure something for that ?
- Are the data erased when deleting a container on marathon?
- Should I have my `ovpn_env.sh` in `/data/myvolume/ovpn_env.sh` or `/data/myvolume/etc/openvpn/ovpn_env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the folowing issue

- https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/2493#issuecomment-196743212

and the docs at

- https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/bd076173b662b12d18e5dd568629a286b242ba91/docs/docs/persistent-volumes.md

Quote:

> Docker volumes with plugin drivers is not available right now.

You'll have to create the volume/mount before you start the container, and map the host folder when you launch the app via Marathon (you do this already). I guess that's why it's currently called "persistent **local** volumes"...

Comment: Thanks @Tobi, I was looking at this : http://innerdot.com/containers/developing-a-stateful-application-on-mesos-and-docker and this : https://github.com/jmspring/mesos-stateful-example . Look fine for him. Where does your quote come from ?

Comment: It's the issue comment... (first link)

Comment: @BigDong The article you posted uses additional arguments for the Docker daemon, and reaches persistence through other mechanisms then the persistent volumes outlined at [persistent-volumes](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/bd076173b662b12d18e5dd568629a286b242ba91/docs/docs/persistent-volumes.md#create-an-application-with-persistent-local-volumes). With the mechanisms from the article, scaling of the application will get interesting I guess

Comment: I want to do exactly what's in the article

Answer (score -1):

Define it in "parameters" part, like this:

```
  "parameters": [
    {
      "key": "volume-driver",
      "value": "glusterfs"
    },
    {
      "key": "volume",
      "value": "openvpn-data:/etc/openvpn"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @BigDong Look carefully please...You define volume in marathon json's "volumes", however, I define that in "parameters". That is why my solution works. I have tested it.